# Dealing with Brute Force Attack

Tags: brute-force-attacks

For the better part of yesterday (and today so far) my server is being attacked with brute force.

I am rather an inexperience admin when it gets passed the basics. I understand how to find things, sometimes understand how to configure things. This attack has got me stressed and tired now.

Every time I think I got it, it comes back.
Here is my CPU usage for the las 24 hours.

[image: CPU usage]

It initialized as an xmlrpc attack with some WordPress sites, I've since disabled that with some plugins - I've also removed the files themselves.

The attacks continue. My auth.log show a lot of attempts. I did some reading, could fail2ban is a great tool for stopping brute force attacks.

Configured it - I think it's right even though there are some "Command not found" errors - it says it banned an IP that was attacking me.

Things are quiet for now.
I check this morning - CPU cranked up.
I run top to see whats taking up all the APU
the program 'host' is running.

```
4274 forge     20   0 1721620   6760   3264 S 98.8  0.3  14:04.99 host                                               
4537 forge     20   0  362804  33656   8664 R  0.3  1.6   0:00.14 php5-fpm                                           
1 root      20   0   33504   3968   2624 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.48 init                                               
2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                           
3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 ksoftirqd/0                                        
5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                       
6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.10 kworker/u2:0
```

It even says by my user. Something else is running this - how can I find out?

Comment: The `host` command can be launched by `fail2ban`. Can you show the output of `ps auxf`?

Comment: Hi -Here is my output for ps aux
http://paste.ofcode.org/XD2ggSwg2xYLj7YRDtmxw4

Comment: I setup fail2ban after the attack began. It seems on a timer, because I can kill the process but usually between an hour or two it starts up. Something already on the machine? A lot of attempts in my auth.log. Hard to tell where to look.

Comment: I can not see any `host` process. Did the CPU load stop?

Comment: Yes, I stopped it. Should I have left it running?

Answer (score 1):

Xmlrpc.php can start dos to other domains keeping your host as source.. You should remove xmlrpc.php , change login page link , or allow login to your known few IPs from .htaccess .

example from wpscan:

[!] The WordPress 'http://cffcinc.com/readme.html' file exists exposing a version number
[+] Interesting header: LINK: http://cffcinc.com/wp-json/; rel="https://api.w.org/", http://cffcinc.com/; rel=shortlink
[+] Interesting header: SERVER: Apache
[+] XML-RPC Interface available under: http://cffcinc.com/xmlrpc.php
[+] WordPress version 4.6.1 (Released on 2016-09-07) identified from advanced fingerprinting, meta generator, readme, links opml, stylesheets numbers

Comment: I got things under control - I did find more malicious files inside the yoast-seo plugin. A .sh file (shell script) which once I removed the plugin altogether it stopped the bots from running. Meanwhile I changed the login links to all WP; xmlrpc; setup banning with fail2ban; and disallowed reading of directories and such. I'll continue working out various aspects as well to keep it secure.